# How to transfer folder(s) from one repository to another repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-branch

I mistakenly created the second repo(**Repo-2**). I can easily delete this and again add the files in the existing repo(**Repo-1**).
But I want to know if I can transfer the folder(**folder-xyz**) from **Repo-2** to **Repo-1**

Also, if it matters, Default branch for **Repo-1** is 'master' and for **Repo-2** is 'main'.

Comment: 1. Clone the repos locally, 2) Manually move the files from the "wrong" repo to the "right place".  3) Update your repos (commit changes).  4) Push your updates back to GitHub.

Comment: Are there also, some set of git commands which can help in doing so.?

Comment: Yes: [clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), [mv](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv), [add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add), [commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) and [push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open CLI in the directory with your local copy of the repository you want to transfer the **folder-xyz** directory to (**Repo-1** in our case).
2. Add additional [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) pointing to the repository you want to transfer the **folder-xyz** directory from (**Repo-2** in our case):

   ```
   git remote add Repo-2 <Repo-2-remote-reposiotry-url>
   ```
3. Fetch the **Repo-2** remote changes

   ```
   git fetch Repo-2
   ```
4. Checkout only the changes related to the **folder-xyz** directory we want to transfer from **Repo-2** `main` to the local **Repo-1** `master` branch:

   ```
   git checkout Repo-2/main -- folder-xyz
   ```
5. Examine the status to see if you did what was intended:

   ```
   git status --branch --short
   ```

   Now you should see all the files from **folder-xyz** added to git index (staging area).
6. If all the changes look good just commit them:

   ```
   git commit --message "Add folder-xyz from Repo-2/main"
   ```